# Installing leaflet.markercluster with npm using mapbox.js's version of leaflet

Tags: npm, leaflet, mapbox, leaflet.markercluster

I currently have mapbox.js@3.0.1 installed, which depends on leaflet@1.0.2. I want to npm install a leaflet plugin leaflet.markercluster@1.0.2, which requires leaflet 1.0.x (which I have through mapbox.js). How can I install leaflet.marketcluster and tell it to find leaflet using mapbox's dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) is indeed already included within [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.0.1/).

So you should not have anything to do in particular to have [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin work with it.

Should you load those 2 libraries the "standard" way (i.e. through `<script>` tags in your HTML page), everything should work without issue:

```html
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.0.3/dist/MarkerCluster.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.0.3/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/HX6yYCvNEvv8rD0khIjG?p=preview

Now since you want to include Leaflet.markercluster through `npm`, I think you can simply have the lib code included in your bundle (e.g. through `import "leaflet.markercluster"`, or whatever is required by your build engine), and the `L.markerClusterGroup` factory should be added without issue.